# What is window.solana type?

Tags: typescript, solana, solana-web3js

I'm a Web3 Developer, trying to add typing for `window.solana` using `Typescript`
Have not found any suitable solutions

Answer (score 0):

Normally in solana-typescript we import the adapters:

```
import {
  PhantomWalletAdapter,
  SlopeWalletAdapter,
  SolflareWalletAdapter,
  SolletWalletAdapter,
} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets";

import type { WalletProviderProps } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
```

then write a function for wallet providers:

```
export function ClientWalletProvider(
  props: Omit<WalletProviderProps, "wallets">
): JSX.Element {
  const wallets = useMemo(
    () => [
      new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
      new SlopeWalletAdapter(),
      new SolflareWalletAdapter(),
      new SolletWalletAdapter(),
    ],
    [YOURNETWORK]
  );
```

If you go into the source code for `PhantomWalletAdapter`.

```
export declare class PhantomWalletAdapter extends BaseMessageSignerWalletAdapter {
    name: WalletName<"Phantom">;
    url: string;
    icon: string;
    private _connecting;
    private _wallet;
    private _publicKey;
    private _readyState;
    constructor(config?: PhantomWalletAdapterConfig);
    get publicKey(): PublicKey | null;
    get connecting(): boolean;
    get connected(): boolean;
    get readyState(): WalletReadyState;
    connect(): Promise<void>;
    disconnect(): Promise<void>;
    sendTransaction(transaction: Transaction, connection: Connection, options?: SendTransactionOptions): Promise<TransactionSignature>;
    signTransaction(transaction: Transaction): Promise<Transaction>;
    signAllTransactions(transactions: Transaction[]): Promise<Transaction[]>;
    signMessage(message: Uint8Array): Promise<Uint8Array>;
    private _disconnected;
}
```

If any wallet installed on your browser, it will inject the solana, so if you type `solana` on console you can write your own type for your project

```
connect: ƒ (e)
disconnect: ƒ ()
isPhantom: true
openBridge: ƒ ()
postMessage: ƒ (e)
request: ƒ (e)
signAllTransactions: ƒ ()
signAndSendTransaction: ƒ (e)
signMessage: ƒ (e)
signTransaction: ƒ (e)
 // _ is indicating that those methods should not be called publicly
// so you dont need to add this to your type
_checkIfValidRequestOrThrow: ƒ (e)
_createHandleIncomingRequestMiddleWare: ƒ ()
_events: i {}
_eventsCount: 0
_handleDisconnect: ƒ ()
_handleMessage: ƒ (e)
_handleStreamDisconnect: ƒ (e)
_incomingJsonRpc: o {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: undefined, _middleware: Array(2)}
_nextRequestId: 1
_outgoingJsonRpc: o {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, _middleware: Array(3)}
_publicKey: null
_responseCallbacks: Map(0) {size: 0}
```